# RVIZ- For frame [base_laser_link]: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist

Tags: ros, rviz, 2dlaserscan, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been going through Laser Scan Data [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_pipeline/Tutorials/IntroductionToWorkingWithLaserScannerData).

I ran the command `$rosbag play Mapping1.bag`. I could see the /base_scan among the rostopic list and echo it to the console. But I am unable to view it on rviz.

I ran `$rosrun rviz rviz` and added display `/base_scan/LaserScan`.

RVIZ is showing Global status warning `Fixed Frame - No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist`
and status error `For frame [base_laser_link]: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist`.
How can I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302741/rviz---for-frame-%5Bbase_laser_link%5D:-fixed-frame-%5Bmap%5D-does-not-exist/) by [naveenk.medi](https://answers.ros.org/users/37305/naveenk.medi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-09-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot system has no transform data between the map frame and your robot frames. You would need some form of odometry or a transform publisher to see your laser scans in the map frame.

To find out which frame your scan is published in, have a look at the `frame_id` in your `/base_scan` message. The message is probably too long or fast to see the header data inside your terminal, so pipe it to `less`:

`rostopic echo /base_scan | less`

Based on your status error I'm guessing the frame_id is `base_laser_link`. To view your laser scan change the RViz Fixed Frame to  that (or any frame connected to it in the tf tree).

---

Originally posted by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) with karma: 249 on 2018-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0